# Handle POST in Python with Google Apps Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, post

I'm hosting my site on Google Apps Engine, Python and I'm trying to handle a simple contact form.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/email" id="contactForm">  
    <h2>Let's get in touch!</h2>
    Name:<br/>
    <input size=35 name="name" placeholder="Feature coming soon!"><br/>
    Email:<br/>
    <input size=35 name="email" placeholder="Feature coming soon!"><br/>
    Subject:<br/>
    <input size=35 name="subject" placeholder="Feature coming soon!"><br/>
    Message:<br/>
    <textarea name="message" rows=15 cols=50 placeholder="Feature coming soon!"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In my app.yaml:

> - url: /email
>     script: email.py

And here is my email.py:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.api import mail

class SendEmail(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        name = self.request.post("name")
        email = self.request.post("email")
        tempSubject = self.request.post("subject")
        msg = self.request.post("body")

        if name is None:
            self.response.out.write("Error: You did not enter a name.")
        elif email is None:
            self.response.out.write("Error: You did not enter an email.")
        elif tempSubject is None:
            self.response.out.write("Error: You did not enter a subject.")
        elif msg is None:
            self.response.out.write("Error: You did not enter a message.")
        else:
            _subject = "Msg from: " + name + "Re: " + tempSubject

            message = mail.EmailMessage(sender = "alexyoung1992@alexyoung.us", to = "alexyoung1992@gmail.com", subject = _subject, body = msg, reply_to = email)
            message.send()

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/email', SendEmail)], debug=True)
run_wsgi_app(application)
self.redirect('/')
```

I get a 500 Server Error:

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this
>   error message and the query that caused it.

Edit: I updated my Python script and debugged all of it on my local machine. Everything runs smoothly but once I try to run it on the server I get the same error. Also you guys can try [running the script yourselves](http://www.alexyoung.us#contact) to see if you get anything different.

Comment: If you check the server logs what does it say?

Answer (score 2):

Python uses "and" not &&
`Name != None && Email != None`

It would be lot easier to debug in your local environment. And show the trackback of the error.

Comment: <type 'exceptions.NameError'>: name 'name' is not defined, however I definitely have the name attribute for all of my form inputs

Comment: You need to give full traceback to see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the server wasn't recognizing some of my variables because I used spaces to indent in some places and tabs in other places. Here is the final code:

```
import cgi
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.api import mail

class SendEmail(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get('name', '')
        email = self.request.get('email', '')
        tempSubject = self.request.get('subject', '')
        msg = self.request.get('message', '')

        if name is None:
            self.response.out.write("Error: You did not enter a name.")
        elif email is None:
            self.response.out.write("Error: You did not enter an email.")
        elif tempSubject is None:
            self.response.out.write("Error: You did not enter a subject.")
        elif msg is None:
            self.response.out.write("Error: You did not enter a message.")
        else:
            _subject = "Message from: " + name + ", Re: " + tempSubject
            msg += "\n\nI can be reached at "
            msg += email

            message = mail.EmailMessage(sender = "foo@bar.com", to = "bar@foo.com")
            message.subject = _subject
            message.body = msg
            message.send()

            self.redirect('/')

def runApp():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/email', SendEmail)], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runApp()
```